# Plain Grid is showing when loading map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, android-widget

I have to load map in my applicatio.I have done everything..1.Getting key and all..But now its is showing as plain grid ..Map is not loading...Please help me..

My activity code:

```
public class Mapcctivity extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mMapView = null;  
     private MapController mc = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapcctivity);

        GeoPoint gPoint = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mView);
        mMapView.setSatellite(true);
        mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mc = mMapView.getController();
        mc.setZoom(15);
        mc.setCenter(gPoint);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


}
```

My Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
  android:id="@+id/mView"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="375dp"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:enabled="true" 
  android:clickable="true" 
  android:apiKey="My key" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES" />

    <application



        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Mapcctivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mapcctivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

When Map is loading my logcat is this:

```
12-03 13:48:17.127: D/dalvikvm(3601): GC freed 9551 objects / 643272 bytes in 402ms
12-03 13:52:18.308: E/ActivityThread(3631): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
12-03 13:52:18.318: E/ActivityThread(3631): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
12-03 13:52:18.357: E/ActivityThread(3631): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
12-03 13:52:19.018: D/dalvikvm(3631): GC freed 1919 objects / 127480 bytes in 249ms
12-03 13:52:19.308: I/MapActivity(3631): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
12-03 13:52:19.317: E/MapActivity(3631): Couldn't get connection factory client
12-03 13:52:19.877: D/dalvikvm(3631): GC freed 4601 objects / 269864 bytes in 121ms
12-03 13:52:24.007: D/dalvikvm(3631): GC freed 13809 objects / 922976 bytes in 137ms
12-03 13:55:31.117: D/dalvikvm(3631): GC freed 9545 objects / 640824 bytes in 163ms
12-03 14:43:38.588: E/ActivityThread(3662): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
12-03 14:43:38.598: E/ActivityThread(3662): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
12-03 14:43:38.797: E/ActivityThread(3662): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
12-03 14:43:40.348: D/dalvikvm(3662): GC freed 1941 objects / 128336 bytes in 219ms
12-03 14:43:41.359: I/MapActivity(3662): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
12-03 14:43:41.359: E/MapActivity(3662): Couldn't get connection factory client
12-03 14:43:42.547: D/dalvikvm(3662): GC freed 4601 objects / 269880 bytes in 137ms
12-03 14:43:47.217: D/dalvikvm(3662): GC freed 13715 objects / 918384 bytes in 226ms
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Have you pass your key here?

```
android:apiKey="My key"
```

Please also know, that your certificate for signing apps is used only when you export. When you press "run" in eclipse app is signed by your "development certificate". As API key is bound to developer certificate, you have to sign your app with your own key, or change API key to the one generated for your development key.

Comment: So, pass the correct key. Please also sign your app and run it on real device. Also - try to add MapView from your code instead layout.xml

Comment: I am passing correct key....I am looking around for this problem for a long time..But still i cant come to a solution..

Comment: As I've written before - try to create MapView with your Java code instead of using xml definition.